# Very strange error regarding gets(string)

Tags: c, string, gets, string.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int a;
   char c[1];
   printf("\n%d\n", a);
   gets(c);
   printf("\n%d\n", a);
   return 0;
}
```

When reading `c` using `gets` the value of `a`, printed previously, is printed as having the value: `0`; when using `scanf("%c", &c);` as a replacement for `gets(c);` the value of `a` stays the same throughout the code.

I can't seem to figure out why this is, could someone please explain how this is possible?

Comment: `gets` is itself strange.

Comment: _'(Using C, not C++)'_ Why tagging [tag:c++] then? Re-tagged ...

Comment: It is not good to print uninitialized values.

Comment: `when using scanf("%c",&c); as a replacement for gets(c); the value of a stays the same throughout the code.`. Hows `a` and `c` are related?

Comment: c++ is practically the same thing as c right? Thought they were XD.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Sure, it's a beginner mistake, but the question was specific, clearly phrased, an (admittedly badly indented) sample case was included and the OP has obviously at least tried to fix it (he talked about what happens when he uses `scanf()` instead). +1 from me to counteract the improper downvotes.

Comment: @Hariprasad they are the variables used, "a" is the int var. and "c" is the char var..

Comment: As a side-note: `&c` is the address of a 1-element array of `char`, not the address of a `char`. This shouldn't cause any problems, but it is not strictly standard conforming and may indicate some misunderstanding...

Answer (score 2):

You only have room for `\0` in the string `a` and `gets()` does not care that there is not enough room.  It evidently overwrote parts of memory resulting in your problem.  Instead of `gets()`, use `fgets()`.

```
char c[100];
if (fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();
size_t len = strlen(c);
if (len && c[len-1] == '\n') c[--len] = '\0';
```

---

C standard (2011) has removed `gets()`from its specification.

---

OP: ... when using `scanf("%c",&c);` as a replacement for `gets(c);` the value of `a` stays the same throughout the code.

This is *good* as `scanf("%c",&c);` should not affect `a`.

If you are hoping for some overwriting of `a` due to a small `c` by using `gets(c);`, you may try `char c[1]; int a;`, but any such code invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably experiencing stack corruption. `gets()` writes input characters to the memory address you passed in (a pointer to the first element of `c`). However, you only allocated 1 character, which is only enough for an empty string (including the null terminator).

This is why `gets()` should never be used. It is not safe because it can overwrite the end of its destination array. Use a safer function instead, like `fgets()`.

Comment: oooh got it, I think, tnx :).

Answer (score 1):

You program is invoking **undefined behavior**
1. unless you are not passing an empty string (`\n`).
2. as `a` is uninitialized.

In this this case anything could happen. You may get the expected or unexpected result, segmentation fault and even the program crash.

Comment: it isnt the 2º one for sure :D.

Comment: Yes. Of course. But I did't understand what do you mean by this :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to get this out of the way, **NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets`: it *will* introduce a point of failure in your program.  It was deprecated in the C99 standard and has been removed from the C2011 standard.  It is *evil*.

Having said all that, let's walk through all the issues in your code.

Remember that in C a *string* is a sequence of characters terminated by a 0-valued byte.  This means that to store an N-character string, you must set aside N+1 `char` elements of storage.  Your `c` array is sized to hold 1 element, meaning the only *string* it can store is the empty string.

The problem with `gets` is that it doesn't know how big the target buffer is; when you pass an array as a parameter, all the called function receives is a pointer to the first element.  If you type in 10 non-whitespace characters, or 100, or 1000, `gets` will happily store the excess to the memory immediately following your array; this is why your `a` variable gets overwritten.  This is also why `gets` has finally been removed from the language standard; that behavior enabled a *lot* of malware exploits.

The reason your `scanf` call *didn't* cause a problem is because you used the `%c` conversion specifier, which only reads a single character from the input stream.  Had you used the `%s` conversion specifier, you would have seen the same result as you did with the `gets` call.

So, you need to do two things:  first, you need to declare `c` to be large enough to hold the largest string you expect plus 1 for the 0 terminator:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 10 // or however large the string needs to be
...
char c[MAX_SIZE+1];
```

then you need to use `fgets` to read the input:

```
if ( fgets( c, sizeof c, stdin ) != NULL )
{
  // work with c
}
```

Comment: 1. Agree about the _evilness_ of `gets()`.  2. Not sure why you mention _non-whitespace_ in "If you type in 10 non-whitespace characters" as `gets()` reads in non-`\n` characters.  3. Note: `gets()` discards the trailing `\n` and `fgets()` does not.